# How to insert value of multiple selectbox in mysql using cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP and try to store the value of multiple select box in mysql

My controller file is:-

```
$this->model_name->save($this->request->data);
```

Value coming in $this->request->data is:-

```
  array(
  [model_name] = array(
  ['field_name'] = array(
  [0] => 'A',
  [1] => 'B' 
   )
 )
 );
```

I'm using the same field name as column name stored in database.

Tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: what your table looks like? if you want to save multiple data in one row you could save it as `json` with `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `saveMany()` -

```
$this->model_name->saveMany($this->request->data);
```

Comment: `saveMany()` is for multiple rows of the same model

Comment: @LucasVieira this is the same condition i think.

Comment: @sgtBOSE on his example I understand multiple data for a field, but he probably wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$options = array('1' => 'Liverpool', '2' => 'Manchester');
echo $this->Form->input('Locations', array(
   'multiple' => 'multiple',
   'type' => 'select',
   'options' => $options
));
```